# PostgreSQL + pg_xlog folder with very old files and how to purge pg_xlog files

Tags: linux, postgresql

Under folder - `/var/lib/pgsql/DB/pg_xlog`

We have very old files as the following:

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       56 May 31  2018 00000002.history
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres      331 Oct 14  2018 000000020000000A00000015.00000020.backup
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 15  2018 000000020000000B00000028
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 18  2018 000000020000000B00000029
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 19  2018 000000020000000B0000002A
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 19  2018 000000020000000B0000002B
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 19  2018 000000020000000B0000002C
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 21  2018 000000020000000B0000002D
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Nov 22  2018 000000020000000B0000002E
```

In order to purge this old files we restart the PostgreSQL service

The other problem is the huge size of `pg_xlog` folder

```
83G     pg_xlog
```

*we restart the PostgreSQL according to many recombination from many posts
but this restart not decrease the `pg_xlog` folder size*

We set also the `wal_keep_segments = 0` in `postgresql.conf` file , then restart The PostgreSQL
But folder  `pg_xlog` still not decreased

Any other suggestion how to purge the old files under - `/var/lib/pgsql/DB/pg_xlog`

Can we simply to delete the files from 2018?

Comment: Is there a gap in the WAL file names, or does `pg_xlog` contain *all* files since Nov 2018?

Comment: What is your `archive_command`?  Is there a replica at all?  If there is, is it up to date with the master?

Comment: What is in "pg_replication_slots" view? What is the setting of "archive_mode" and "archive_command" parameters?  What is in "/var/lib/pgsql/DB/pg_xlog/archive_status"?